# Index Error: boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 0; dimension is 2000 but corresponding boolean dimension is 1001

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have a list of len 2000 and when i try converting it to `numpy` array i get this error:

```
Index Error: boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 0;
  dimension is 2000 but corresponding boolean dimension is 1001
```

Code Snippet :

```
NCR = NCR + GROUPED 
print(len(NCR))               # 2000 
INCR_RESULT = np.array(NCR)   # ERROR!
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure that line throws the error? Could you add the full error stacktrace ?

Comment: I am returning the INCR_RESULT to a function that s calling the function that's written above.

Comment: As far as I know, the lines of code you show could not throw an `IndexError`. Could you add your full error stacktrace to see which line exactly causes the error?